# how to resovle multiple refs in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set dynamic ref in hooks component, but it seems not support in react hooks.

```
 coupons.map((item: TCouponItem, index: number) => (
                                        <CouponItem
                                            couponItem={item} key={`received${index}`}
                                            ref={`received${index}`}
                                            refName={`received${index}`}
                                            onDescClick={(refName: string) => { onDescClick(refName); }}
                                        />))
```

Does it any ways to relize this

Answer (score 0):

You can't create ref by simply writing `ref=myref`. You first need to instantiate the ref with `const ref = useRef(null)`. Then you can add `ref={ref}` to the component.